# Making image as a css

Tags: css

I tried to create this canvas in css:

[image]

this is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/kyfha/35/

I have a problem only with the circle border, it's not exactly like the canvas.

this is my css:

```
.PersonaCanvas {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 12px solid rgb(238,238,238);
    border-left: 12px solid rgb(238,238,238);
    border-right: 12px solid rgb(238,238,238);
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

.PersonaCanvas img {
  display: block;
  margin-top:16px;
  width:100%;
  height:80%;
}
```

and my html:

```
<div class="PersonaCanvas">
    <img src="http://s8.postimg.org/ij71l6xol/New_Pers_achiever_1.png"/>
</div>
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: Your image points to lacalhost

Comment: @nikans, I'm sorry.. I updated my jsfiddle and image. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you set a width and height of the container to 100px, but when you add a border, it *automatically* grows in size; if you inspect, you have the final width which is 124px, which comes from the 100px you set, along with the 12px border-left and another 12px border-right.  You would either have to manually change it to accommodate the size to add up to 100px, or you can use a **css3** method of `box-sizing: border-box` to do the calculation for you.  Also, we had to change the width of the img to 80%, since you want it to stay in proportion to its height within the container.  Lastly, the size of the img is fixed, but we have to align its `margin: 16px auto 0`.  Try this [updated one](http://jsfiddle.net/kyfha/40/):

```
.PersonaCanvas {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 12px solid rgb(238,238,238);
    border-left: 12px solid rgb(238,238,238);
    border-right: 12px solid rgb(238,238,238)
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.PersonaCanvas img {
    display: block;
    margin: 16px auto 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the width of the border decreasing is cause by the lack of a bottom border (*which is assumed to be 0 pixels*)

So by adding a transparent bottom border you can make the width consistent.. (*but you will need extra elements to make the ends be curved*)

```
border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kyfha/39/

Comment: border-bottom is a clever solution that fixes the proportions of the image, but it does not recreate the 'canvas' art on a 1:1 size, it scales it to a slightly larger size instead.

Comment: actually it would still need
  margin:16px auto 0;
  width:80%;

Comment: True, might as well use border-bottom and box-sizing to cover both ends.

Answer (score 1):

I added two other div's. One for a white circle to cover part of the solid bottom border. And I also added the css elements and made te absolute so they will still fit wherever you need them. The border ends are not perfect, but if you made a white image with the correct edhe you have and inseted it into the thrid div tag, you will be perfect.

I hope this helps :)

http://jsfiddle.net/kyfha/44/

```
<div class="PersonaCanvas">
    <img src="http://s8.postimg.org/ij71l6xol/New_Pers_achiever_1.png"/>
</div>
<div class="PersonaCanvas2">

</div>
<div class="PersonaCanvas3">

</div>
```

Here is the CSS

I changed the size of the image slightly and moved it around a little to give you your image.

```
.PersonaCanvas {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    overflow: hidden;  
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}

.PersonaCanvas2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-top: 12px solid rgb(238,238,238);
    border-left: 12px solid rgb(238,238,238);
    border-right: 12px solid rgb(238,238,238);
    border-bottom: 12px solid rgb(238,238,238);
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;  
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.PersonaCanvas3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #FFF;
    top: 110px;
    left: 46px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.PersonaCanvas img {
    display: block;
    margin-top:16px;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: -0px;
}
```

Basicallly I have two instances of the div tag and the image is in one without the border or the radius.